# Отличие TargetRpc от ClientRpc в Mirror

Tags: unity3d

Чем отличаются атрибуты TargetRpc от ClientRpc в Mirror Networking в Unity3d? Я их протестил и разницы не увидел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TargetRpc это выполнить конкретное действие над конкретным игровым объектом который имеет компонент NetworkIdentity. Лично я ещё использую ссылку на этот объект, передавая в аргументы (NetworkConnection client)

ClientRpc это выполнится на всех клиентах в определённом радиусе, который настраивается в Mirror Networking